# components with different values on different views

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I need a particular component which I created to render differently on two different views. How is it possible to pass different colors for the component button on different views?

**View1:**

```
const View1 = () => {
  return (
    <View {...this.props} style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        {'More View construction'}
      </Text>
      <AButton />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**View2:**

```
 const View2 = () => {
   return (
     <View {...this.props} style={styles.container}>
       <Text>
         {'More View construction'}
       </Text>
       <AButton />
     </View>
   );
};
```

**Button component:**

```
 import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
 const shadowStyle = {
 shadowOpacity: 100,
   shadowOffset: {
  width: 100,
   height: 5,
  },
  shadowRadius: 20,
 elevation: 2,
 };
   const AButton = () => {
     return (
       <ActionButton buttonColor={colors.red} shadowStyle={shadowStyle}>
         <ActionButton.Item buttonColor={colors.yellow}>
           <Text style={styles.actionButtonIcon}>
             {'xyz'}
           </Text>
         </ActionButton.Item>
       </ActionButton>
     );
   };
```

Could anyone suggest me how to implement change of color and shadow style on the two different views.

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize rendering of your components you can pass different props to your component.

**Example**

```
const View1 = () => {
 return (
   <View {...this.props} style={styles.container}>
     <Text>
       {'More View construction'}
     </Text>
     <AButton
       shadowStyle={/*some custom shadow style object */}
       buttonColor={/*some custom button color */} />
   </View>
 );
};
```

---

```
const View2 = () => {
 return (
   <View {...this.props} style={styles.container}>
     <Text>
       {'More View construction'}
     </Text>
     <AButton
       shadowStyle={/*some other custom shadow style object */}
       buttonColor={/*some other custom button color */} />
   </View>
 );
};
```

---

```
const AButton = (props) => {
    return (
      <ActionButton buttonColor={props.buttonColor} shadowStyle={props.shadowStyle}>
        <ActionButton.Item buttonColor={colors.yellow}>
          <Text style={styles.actionButtonIcon}>
            {'xyz'}
          </Text>
        </ActionButton.Item>
      </ActionButton>
    );
};
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it wont take the values for the action floating button? any idea why and how to resolve it? @bennygenel

Comment: I can't say anything unless I see your complete example